# Adding a font for use in ReportLab

Tags: python, fonts, reportlab

I'm trying to add a font to the python ReportLab so that I can use it for a function.  The function is using canvas.Canvas to draw a bunch of text in a PDF, nothing complicated, but I need to add a fixed width font for layout issues.

When I tried to register a font using what little info I could find, that seemed to work.  But when I tried to call .addFont('fontname') from my Canvas object I keep getting

"PDFDocument instance has no attribute 'addFont'"

Is the function just not implemented?  How do I get access to fonts other than the 10 or so default ones that are listed in .getAvailableFonts?  Thanks.

Some example code of what I'm trying to make happen:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
c = canvas.Canvas('label.pdf')
c.addFont('TestFont') #This throws the error listed above, 
                      #regardless of what argument I use (whether it refers 
                      #to a font or not).
c.drawString(1,1,'test data here')
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

To register the font, I tried

```
from reportlab.lib.fonts import addMapping
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('TestFont', 'ghettomarquee.ttf'))
addMapping('TestFont', 0, 0, 'TestFont')
```

where 'ghettomarquee.ttf' was just a random font I had lying around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
c.setFont('TestFont')
c.drawString(1,1,'test data here')
```

`setFont` to set the font name you're going to use, and `drawString`.

ReportLab will automatically embed the font if you use it in the document, you don't have to manually add it after you've registered the font globally under a name.

Comment: did you mean `c.setFont('TestFont')` in the first line?